# Who Came up with the Galactic Barrier Concept?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre

In specific universes, [this](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheMilkyWayIsTheOnlyWay) [is](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113854/who-or-what-created-the-galactic-barrier-in-star-trek) [usually](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperspace_disturbance_beyond_the_edge_of_the_galaxy) explained rather well in universe.  But, what I'm looking for here is a more out of universe explanation.  **Where did the idea of a galactic barrier come from and why have other works adopted it?**

To be clear, it's pretty obvious that inter galaxy travel is generally unfeasible even in sci fi, but I want to know why many works make it downright impossible with an actual barrier that seems pointless.

**Edit:** For those requesting a definition of barrier.  The barrier would be some kind of region or existence that literally makes travel impossible or near impossible.  It doesn't have to be physical or completely prevent access, but it does have to make the ridiculous concept of inter-galaxy travel even more impossible.

**Examples** *Most of these are taken from the TV Tropes list*

1. The Star Pit ~

> only people with a specific set of psychological
>       issues can handle going outside the galaxy

2. The Last Legionary ~

> extended stays in Overlight drive humans insane, making it impossible to have a functioning crew at the other end of the trip

3. The Culture ~

> the Grid — the barrier between this universe the other ultraverses/infraverses ships use to travel— changes properties in extra-galactic space, making ships travel slower.

4. Star Trek ~ [As explained in the link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113854/who-or-what-created-the-galactic-barrier-in-star-trek)

Comment: @Gandalf Star Wars adopted it as well, but that may be mostly legends now.  It wasn't a physical barrier, but one that prevented hyperspace travel.  As I linked too.  There are probably more, too.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60083/why-didnt-humans-try-to-settle-other-galaxies) suggest some version of "impossible to travel beyond our galaxy" applied to Asimov's *Foundation* series, although the reasons aren't really spelled out so it isn't necessarily any type of barrier.

Comment: I can figure out what a Galactic Barrier is from context clues, but an explicit definition would aid the question.

Comment: @Hypnosifl There's no real sound barrier or speed of light barrier, either.

Comment: @Axelrod - Depends how literally you mean "barrier"--there is a speed of light barrier in the sense that it would take an infinite amount of energy to reach light speed. Anyway, why do you bring this up in response to my comment about *Foundation*? He didn't suggest that the reason for the difficulty of leaving the galaxy was *either* a spatial barrier *or* a "barrier" on hyperspace velocity akin to the speed-of-light barrier.

Comment: @Hypnosifl We still refer to it as a barrier even though there is no physical implementation stopping us.  A Galactic barrier could be something so simple as, in Star Wars, the distances being too vast for any sane person to take on.

Comment: @Axelrod - Gotcha. Although I tend to think of "barrier" referring to some specific threshold, like a precise region of space or precise speed that can't be crossed, rather than a fuzzier matter of ever-increasing practical difficulty (for example, I've never heard of anyone talk of a 'barrier' ruling out interstellar travel even though the practical difficulties would be huge with near-future technology). Also, in Star Wars I don't think it's just a matter of distances being too great, but difficulty finding [hyperlanes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperlane) leading to other galaxies.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Not having one leads to the other. Also, I'm pretty sure hyperspace is one of the "too many chefs, too little kitchen" deals in the EU, but in the case of the sound barriers, yes -- it was just something that needed more effort and sturdier design than we had.

Comment: I'm not sure Star Wars is the best example of this, it is never mentioned in Disney cannon and in the EU the yuzhan'vong (Probably butchered that spelling...) were from another galaxy so it did happen even if it wasn't common for logistical reasons.

Comment: I have done a bit of clarification on what a barrier consists of and added a few examples.  Mostly from the tv tropes link in the top part of my question.  Let me know if it is still ambiguous.  And yes, for those wondering, this is a history-of question, not a question asking for why any of those things work.

Comment: "the barrier between this universe the other ultraverses/infraverses ships use to travel" - this sounds like a barrier between *universes*, which is quite a level above travelling between *galaxies* in one universe.

Comment: I'm perhaps not remembering correctly, but wasn't there a galactic barrier in one of the Lensmen books?

Answer (score 3):

Probably *Star Trek* since the galactic Barrier is in the second pilot episode ["Where no Man Has Gone Before"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Where_No_Man_Has_Gone_Before_%28episode%29), written by Samuel Peebles,  that was written and filmed between and April and July 1965 and aired in the USA on 22 September, 1966.

It is possible that there may have been galactic barriers in some obscure earlier science fiction stories published in the previous three decades or so.  But *Star Trek* should be considered first until and unless a famous example earlier than 1965 is found.

Comment: You mean 1965, right?

Comment: I read over that Memory Alpha article. The barrier is encountered at the edge of galactic space. The ship's sensors don't pick up anything, but the deflectors insist that there is something there. After they try and go forward, the crew is affected by a mysterious force that kills some of them and transforms others.